# OpenLayers 6 "panning" map with Cypress

Tags: pointers, events, cypress, openlayers-6, panning

I'm trying to test the panning action in open layers but I can't get the map to move.
The versions I am using are these:

- OpenLayers: 6.10.0
- Cypress: 9.7.0

This is the code I have:

```
When('I pan the map to a different area', () => {
  cy.wait(3000)

  cy.get('.ol-layer canvas').trigger('pointerdown', {
    clientX: 900,
    clientY: 300,
    force: true,
    pointerId: 1,
  })
  cy.get('.ol-layer canvas').trigger('pointermove', {
    x: 600,
    y: 200,
    force: true,
    pointerId: 2,
  })
  cy.get('.ol-layer canvas').trigger('pointermove', {
    x: 300,
    y: 100,
    force: true,
    pointerId: 1,
  })
  cy.wait(2000)
  cy.get('.ol-layer canvas').trigger('pointerup', { force: true, pointerId: 1 })
})
```

Comment: Try using `.ol-viewport` for the event target

Comment: @Mike It doesn't work that way either.

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with the same issue.
Eventually I made it work, at least partially. The only thing is that the first pointermove is ignored but the rest do just fine. I have no idea why this happens.

This is the code. Hope it works for you as well

```
cy.get('.ol-viewport')
  .trigger('pointerdown', {
    eventConstructor: 'MouseEvent',            
    clientX: 891,
    clientY: 544,
    force: true,
    isPrimary: true
  })

cy.wait(1000)  

cy.get('.ol-viewport')
  .trigger('pointermove', { clientX: 871, clientY: 530 })      
cy.wait(1000)  

cy.get('.ol-viewport')
  .trigger('pointermove', { clientX: 871, clientY: 500 })      
cy.wait(1000)  

cy.get('.ol-viewport')
  .trigger('pointermove', { clientX: 891, clientY: 510 })      
cy.wait(1000)  

cy.get('.ol-viewport')
  .trigger('pointerup', {      
    eventConstructor: 'MouseEvent',
    force: true,
  })
```